# Copying worksheet from one workbook to another

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet, copying

I'm new to Excel and am trying to get my VBA to copy a worksheet to another workbook with this code:

```
Sub CopySheetl()
Dim wkbSource As Workbook
Dim wkbDest As Workbook
Dim shtToCopy As Worksheet

Set wkbSource = Workbooks.Open("C:\Documents and Settings\wong.zuowei\My Documents\Dropbox\SIP\Report Templates\New Documentation System\2014\June Lines Report.xlsm")
Set wkbDest = Workbooks.Open("C:\Documents and Settings\wong.zuowei\My Documents\Dropbox\SIP\Report Templates\New Documentation System\2014\2014 Lines Report.xlsx")

'set shttocopy = wkbsoure.sheets("name of worksheet")

Set shtToCopy = wkbSource.Sheets(9)

shtToCopy.PasteSpecial wkbDest.Sheets(1)

wkbDest.Save


End Sub
```

The end result is nothing. Nothing happens. I mean the code runs fine but it does nothing. I need help!

Edit:

I tried another code as suggested:

```
Sub copy_sh()

Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
Dim destSheet As Worksheet

'' copy from the source
Workbooks.Open filename:="C:\Documents and Settings\wong.zuowei\My Documents\Dropbox\SIP\Report Templates\New Documentation System\2014\June Lines Report.xlsm"
Set sourceSheet = Worksheets("JuneSummary")
sourceSheet.Activate
sourceSheet.Cells.Select
Selection.copy

'' paste to the destination
Workbooks.Open filename:="C:\Documents and Settings\wong.zuowei\My Documents\Dropbox\SIP\Report Templates\New Documentation System\2014\2014 Lines Report.xlsx"
Set destSheet = Worksheets("June")
destSheet.Activate
destSheet.Cells.Select
destSheet.Paste

'' save & close
ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

The code ran without compile errors but nothing happened too.

Comment: How do you know the code runs and doesn't exit in between? And if it does, can you put breakpoints and check where you think the issue could be?

Comment: Why not just use .Copy() and .Save method

Comment: @hnk - no compiling errors came up when i ran it

Comment: @Sky how do i do that???

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know if it works

```
Sub CopySheetl()
    Dim wkbSource As Workbook
    Dim wkbDest As Workbook
    Dim shtToCopy As Worksheet

    Set wkbSource = Workbooks.Open("C:\Documents and Settings\wong.zuowei\My Documents\Dropbox\SIP\Report Templates\New Documentation System\2014\June Lines Report.xlsm")
    Set wkbDest = Workbooks.Open("C:\Documents and Settings\wong.zuowei\My Documents\Dropbox\SIP\Report Templates\New Documentation System\2014\2014 Lines Report.xlsx")

    'set shttocopy = wkbsoure.sheets("name of worksheet")

    ‘Set shtToCopy = wkbSource.Sheets(9)

    ‘shtToCopy.PasteSpecial wkbDest.Sheets(1)

    wkbSource.Sheets(9).Copy after:=wkbDest.Sheets(1)

    wkbDest.Save


End Sub
```

Comment: Your shtToCopy is not even assigned.

Comment: @moiety design an error came up when running: "method or data member not found" at line the line "wkbSource.Sheets(9).Copy after:=shtToCopy.Sheets(1)"

Comment: I just changed `shtToCopy.Sheets(1)` to `wkbDest.Sheets(1)` sorry I just use the worksheet rather than the workbook

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub CopySheet2()
Dim wkbSource As Workbook
Dim wkbDest As Workbook
Dim shtToCopy As Worksheet

Set wkbSource = Workbooks.Open("C:\Documents and Settings\wong.zuowei\My Documents\Dropbox\SIP\Report Templates\New Documentation System\2014\June Lines Report.xlsm")
Set wkbDest = Workbooks.Open("C:\Documents and Settings\wong.zuowei\My Documents\Dropbox\SIP\Report Templates\New Documentation System\2014\2014 Lines Report.xlsx")

'set shttocopy = wkbsoure.sheets("name of worksheet")

Set shtToCopy = wkbSource.Sheets(9)

shtToCopy.Copy After:=wkbDest.Sheets(1)

wkbDest.Save


End Sub
```

Comment: it didnt work! the vba window performed the code but nothing really changed

Comment: Please try again, remember to close your source and dest workbook before running the code.

Comment: but if i close the source workbook the code in the vba will close too